# Is it mandatory to give targetversion in build gradle or manifest?

Tags: android, build.gradle, target

If I was not given any targetversion in gradle then, is it will take latest version, or which version it will choose, I build the apk without giving any targetversion, so when I will get problem of this targetversion is mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Not mandatory but is strongly recommended.

`targetSdkVersion` has nothing to do with adding the latest version or your compiling, it will just allow you to use the features available in the SDK you are targeting.

**For example**.
If you are targeting SDK 23, Then IDE will mark you errors whenever you are using critical permissions in your code. it will tell you to put a permission check.
If you target SDK 22, then you are free to use critical permissions without putting a permission check.

for the above situation, your app is tested and works fine in Lollipop or below, but it might crash in Marshmallow.

as per Documentation, it says [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

> Specifies the API Level on which the application is designed to run.
>   In some cases, this allows the application to use manifest elements or
>   behaviors defined in the target API Level, rather than being
>   restricted to using only those defined for the minimum API Level.

Comment: If I am not given any target version, is it will take latest version as target version, like i have given compiled sdk version is 23, so is it will work for api level 24

Comment: No, as i explained in above example. it got nothing to do with the Compilation. it will only allow you to use the features available in the targeted version. It might work on API level 24 if you are properly using features introduced in API level 24